# Not able to register a tap on the screen using tapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to build a chat app using Firebase. I am trying to implement a tap gesture in order to dismiss the keyboard when it's on. Unfortunately, nothing happen when you tap on the screen. I tried different things, same result. I will appreciate it if someone knows the reason why it's not working. I tried with the parameter numberOfTouches as well, same result.

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Declare instance variables here

    // We've pre-linked the IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var sendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var messageTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var messageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        messageTableView.delegate = self
        messageTableView.dataSource = self

        //TODO: Set yourself as the delegate of the text field here:
        messageTextfield.delegate = self

        //TODO: Set the tapGesture here:
        //messageTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableViewTapped))
        messageTableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        //TODO: Register your MessageCell.xib file here:
        messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell

        let messageArray = ["1","2","3"]
        cell.messageBody.text = messageArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        return 3
    }

    @objc func tableViewTapped (){
        messageTableView.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.heightConstraint.constant = 380
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = 50
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set endEditing of the whole view true by updating your selector method:

```
@objc func tableViewTapped (){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Also you might want to add the gestureRecognizer to `view` itself instead of `tableView`, because it might cause further problems by overlapping with `didSelectRowAt` method.

If that doesnt work try to add following in your `viewDidLoad` (In this case you wont need a `gestureRecognizer`):

```
messageTableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

Comment: Thanks . I tried to set endEditing with the whole view . It is working now . Thanks